¿Cómo configuro coc.vim para que no me aparezca los tipos de mis variables en el buffer?
Me refiero a estas indicaciones que me muestra coc.vim:

Estoy usando neovim, como linter uso pyright pero quiero que no me aparezca en cualquier lenguaje que este usando.
He configurado coc-settings-json de la siguiente forma:
{
"languageserver": {
    "pyright": {
        "command": "pyright-langserver",
        "args": ["--stdio"],
        "filetypes": ["python"],
        "settings": {
            "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
                "/home/cronos/miniforge3/lib/python3.1/site-packages/"
            ],
            "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off",
            "python.analysis.typeHint": "false",
            "initializationOptions": {
                "typeCheckingMode": "off",  

            },
        }
    }
},

La ubicación de coc-settings-json es la predeterminada ~/config/nvim
Creía que typeHint era la configuración que tenia que cambiar pero al parecer no es eso.
Probablemente solo necesite el nombre correcto de la propiedad asociada para solucionar mi problema, pero eso solo solucionaría el problema con python y yo lo quiero para cualquier lenguaje ¿Cúal es la manera mas práctica de hacerlo?
(Nota: no quiero usar otras opciones a coc.vim)

Debes agregar a tu coc-settings.json la propiedad "inlayHint.enable" con el valor false
Link de la  documentacion
Tu coc-settings.json debe lucir asi:
{
 "languageserver": {
    "pyright": {
        "command": "pyright-langserver",
        "args": ["--stdio"],
        "filetypes": ["python"],
        "settings": {
            "python.analysis.extraPaths": [
                "/home/cronos/miniforge3/lib/python3.1/site-packages/"
            ],
            "python.analysis.typeCheckingMode": "off",
            "python.analysis.typeHint": "false",
            "initializationOptions": {
                "typeCheckingMode": "off",  

            },
        }
    }
  },
  "inlayHint.enable": false
}


Ejemplo:
Con "inlayHint.enable": true

En esta imagen, es claro que al activar dicha propiedad se muestran las sugerencias para los parámetros de las funciones y los tipos que retorna, aun cuando los tipos no estén definidos.
Con "inlayHint.enable": false

Si la deshabilitamos se dejan de mostrar tanto las sugerencias de parametros como las de tipos de retorno.
